# How get getters in freemarker template?

Tags: spring, freemarker

I add some variables to ModelAndView

```
AuthLkUser authLkUser = authService.getAuthLkUser(msisdn);   
LkAuth lkAuthByMsisdn = authService.getLkAuthByMsisdn(authLkUser);

modelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("login_type");
        modelAndView.addObject("authLkUser",authLkUser);
        modelAndView.addObject("lkAuthByMsisdn",lkAuthByMsisdn);
```

How can I get fields of this objects in fremarker template?

```
<#if ${lkAuthByMsisdn.bySms} == 1>
        <form action="" method="get">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">По смс</button>
        </form>
        </#if>
```

it not work

```
${authLkUser.bySms}
```

I have getters and setters.

```
public class LkAuth {
    private @Getter @Setter int ppId;
    private @Getter @Setter int bySms;
    private @Getter @Setter int byPin;
    private @Getter @Setter int byIp;
    private @Getter @Setter int status;
}
```

Comment: At leas show us `AuthLkUser ` class

Comment: simple pojo with getters and setters

Comment: As you wish. If you don't give us information, we cannot help you.

Comment: I add. This helped you?

Comment: What is this `@Getter` annotation?

Comment: https://projectlombok.org/

Comment: And are you sure, that `lkAuthByMsisdn.bySms` is really equal to `1`?

Comment: My IDE It illuminates the red line is the expression

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with getters, it's a simple syntactical error. You should write `<#if lkAuthByMsisdn.bySms == 1>`. FreeMarker for a while even explains this in the error message; you may should update it to get better error messages.